# Python coding calculator

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

I created this code to build a calculator that will automatically call the right arithmetic function based on the user input.
I have written a sample functions. I wrote for addition on the bottom as a comment.

When I run the code, in the for loop it should match the user's input to the list for addition in order to confirm the arithmetic function to use, in this case, it does not work.
Also "Invalid arithmetic function" gets printed anyways for whatever your input is.
I am new to python and still learning. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
from Calculator import addition

divisions = ["division", "divide", "/"]
multiplications = ["multiplication", "multiply", "*", "x", "X"]
additions = ["addition", "add", "+"]
subtractions = ["subtraction", "subtract", "-"]

answers = 0

problem = input("Which arithmetic function do you want to perform? ")
num1 = int(input("What is your first number? "))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number? "))

if type(problem) == str:
    for i in additions:
        if problem == i:
            answers = addition(num1, num2)
            print(answers)
        else:
            print("Invalid arithmetic function")
            break
else:
    print("Invalid arithmetic functions")

print(answers)

#def addition(num, num0):
#    answer = num + num0
#    return answer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a else within the for loop. Wait for the loop to end as the last item in the list could be the one matching the problem string.

```
divisions = ["division", "divide", "/"]
multiplications = ["multiplication", "multiply", "*", "x", "X"]
additions = ["addition", "add", "+"]
subtractions = ["subtraction", "subtract", "-"]

answers = None

problem = input("Which arithmetic function do you want to perform? ")
num1 = int(input("What is your first number? "))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number? "))
if type(problem) == str:
    for i in additions:
        if problem == i:
            answers = num1+ num2
            print(answers)
    if(answers == None):
            print("Invalid arithmetic functions")
        
else:
    print("Invalid arithmetic functions")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem with your code

```py
for i in additions:
   if problem == i:
```

here first `"addition"` is not `"+"` so loop is breaking on first time.

#### Solution

instead of loop use direct `if` condition

```py
if problem in additions:
```

#### check this code

```py
divisions = ["division", "divide", "/"]
multiplications = ["multiplication", "multiply", "*", "x", "X"]
additions = ["addition", "add", "+"]
subtractions = ["subtraction", "subtract", "-"]

answers = 0

problem = input("Which arithmetic function do you want to perform? ")
num1 = int(input("What is your first number? "))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number? "))

def addition(num, num0):
   answer = num + num0
   return answer

if type(problem) == str:
  if problem in additions:
      answers = addition(num1, num2)
      print(answers)
  else:
      print("Invalid arithmetic function")
else:
    print("Invalid arithmetic functions")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substantially simplify your code as below:

```
divisions = ["division", "divide", "/"]
multiplications = ["multiplication", "multiply", "*", "x", "X"]
additions = ["addition", "add", "+"]
subtractions = ["subtraction", "subtract", "-"]

problem = input("Which arithmetic function do you want to perform? ")
if problem in additions:
    num1 = int(input("What is your first number? "))
    num2 = int(input("What is your second number? "))
    print('Answer is:', num1 + num2)
else:
    print("Invalid arithmetic function")
```

Answer (score 0):

When debugging your program, here is what I found the problem to be:

```
for i in additions:
            if problem == i:
                answers = addition(num1, num2)
                print(answers)
            else:
                print("Invalid arithmetic function")
                break
```

The for loop will search through the additions list and output a result for every item. To stop that, remove the print functions and only print after the calculations are done.

There are multiple ways to re-implement the "Invalid arithmetic function" error message. One of the simplest being to put the code block inside a function and return the value.

Here is the working version:

```
    divisions = ["division", "divide", "/"]
    multiplications = ["multiplication", "multiply", "*", "x", "X"]
    additions = ["addition", "add", "+"]
    subtractions = ["subtraction", "subtract", "-"]

    answers = 0

    problem = input("Which arithmetic function do you want to perform? ")
    num1 = int(input("What is your first number? "))
    num2 = int(input("What is your second number? "))

    def addition(num, num0):
        answer = num + num0
        return answer

    def calculateAnswer():
        if type(problem) == str:
        for i in additions:
          if problem == i:
            answers = addition(num1, num2)
            return answers
      #If an answer is not returned, the code below will execute
      return "Invalid arithmetic function"

    print(calculateAnswer());
```